# Why is ldap_bind failing to authenticate against SimpleAD?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, aws-directory-services

I have a AD **ldap.patontheback.org** and I'm trying to do `ldap_bind` with the default administrator account. The same account that I can successfully use remote desktop with to administrate the users.

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap://172.31.22.45");
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
ldap_bind($ldapconn, "cn=Administrator,dc=ldap,dc=patontheback,dc=org", "<my password>");
```

Which can connect, but doesn't authenticate:

```
ldap_sasl_bind_s
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 172.31.22.45:389
ldap_new_socket: 3
ldap_prepare_socket: 3
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 172.31.22.45:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 3 tm: -1 async: 0
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ldap_result ld 0x2bb31e0 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x2bb31e0 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x2bb31e0 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x2bb31e0 Connections:
* host: 172.31.22.45  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Mon May  9 13:45:10 2016


** ld 0x2bb31e0 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x2bb31e0 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x2bb31e0 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x2bb31e0 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x2bb31e0 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x2bb31e0 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x2bb31e0 msgid 1 all 1
read1msg: ld 0x2bb31e0 msgid 1 message type bind
read1msg: ld 0x2bb31e0 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x2bb31e0 msgid 1
request done: ld 0x2bb31e0 msgid 1
res_errno: 49, res_error: <Simple Bind Failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_parse_result
ldap_msgfree
ldap_err2string
PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials in php shell code on line 1
```

I've tripple checked the password is correct. The IP to LDAP I've gotten from the windows server:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup ldap.patontheback.org
Server:  AWS-4A06F0BDB6.ldap.patontheback.org
Address:  172.31.22.45

Name:    ldap.patontheback.org
Addresses:  172.31.22.45
          172.31.2.194
```

What on earth am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could get it to work using UPN as the identifie:

```
ldap_bind($ldapconn, "Administrator@ldap.patontheback.org", "<password>");
```

It works but it doesn't explain why the other way doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming to this question as I have later on, the correct way to do this would be

`ldap_bind($ldapconn, "cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=ldap,dc=patontheback,dc=org", "<my password>");`

The `cn=Users` is a required path to be included.